# Set the focus on the email field on the login page

Tags: feature-request, login

Whenever I want to log in, I need to set the focus to the "Email" field on the login page. I believe it should be the default: what else would we want to do besides entering our email, then password on a page that is specifically dedicated to logging in?

I currently use a TamperMonkey one-liner to do the job, but having it by default would be even greater.

**EDIT 2022:** it's been 6 years and still no autofocus. I curse the world every single day because of this oversight. I even started using the login page as an example of what not to do in talks about accessibility.

Comment: I always click on the google button. So focus wouldn't affect me either way..

Comment: Yeah, this would make my password manager configuration so much easier. Instead of adding a 5s delay (to wait for the page to load), then type TAB **fifteen times**, just to get to the username field. Yeah, please do it, doesn't hurt.

Answer (score -2):

No, I don't want that.

I am using Google to log in, so having a text field focused is just a distraction, and for new users who also use a non-SE provider and are not familiar with how logging in works, it will be very confusing: they will try posting their Google credentials there and wonder why it's not working.

Just in case the system can somehow identify usage of Stack Exchange OpenID on the machine this will be useful, not for all users.